# Issue with polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am  trying to plot some values on a polar plot. The code is as follows:

```
def plot_values(data):
    bridge = CvBridge()

    fig = figure(figsize=(4,4))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
    w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()

    plot([0,0],[0,1],  color=(0.5,0.5,0.5), linewidth = 3)
    plot([1*pi/2,1*pi/2],[0,1], color=(0.5,0.5,0.5), linewidth = 3)
    plot([2*pi/2,2*pi/2],[0,1],  color=(0.5,0.5,0.5), linewidth = 3)
    plot([3*pi/2,3*pi/2],[0,1],  color=(0.5,0.5,0.5), linewidth = 3)

    HAS= len(HAS_names)*4
    radii=np.repeat(data,HAS) 
    width = 2*np.pi/HAS
    for i in range(0, len(HAS_names)):
      radii[i] = AUC_value[HAS_names[i]]/HAS_frames[i] #assignment done through lists
    theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/HAS)
    bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

    xT=PLT.xticks()[0]
    xL=['','HAS','','HAD','','TAS','','TAD']
   PLT.xticks(xT, xL)
   for r,bar in zip(radii, bars):
     bar.set_facecolor( cm.jet(r/10.))
     bar.set_alpha(0.5)
  fig.canvas.draw()
  canvas = PLT.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
  canvas.draw()
```

I get the output as follows:

[image: Polar_plot]

I am trying to plot the values occurring in the quadrant labeled HAS and rest on the region need to blank. I tried removing `radii=np.repeat(data,HAS)` and declare it as `global variable` within the function itself, but I needed to assign some value to `radii` initially before the `for` loop. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you want all the data showing up in the "HAS" quadrant and nothing in the "HAD", "TAS", "TAD" quadrants?  Should just have to modify theta for that, no?

Comment: Yes, I want only the values to be plotted on "HAS" quadrant. I don't know which variable of theta to be modified.

Comment: I know that the values plotted on other quadrants are done by this statement `radii=np.repeat(data,HAS)` and the values on "HAS" quadrant is done through `radii[i] = AUC_value[HAS_names[i]]/HAS_frames[i]`.

Comment: As @tnknepp said, your thetas are going from 0 to 2 pi, if you want the data to live in the "HAS" quadrant, just change 2*pi to pi/2.  Unless that's not it, in which case this question is extremely unclear. Especially since your last comments about global variables don't seem to make much sense in context.